# How to format 2 string columns into date time value using Azure mapping data flows

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can you please help  me with my problem ,

I have 2 columns Tran_date & Tran time like below which are feeding from my source as a string value without special characters to separate month,date &year similarly tran_time  for time . Now how can i transform them as a datetime value like shown in below example using Azure Data Flows.

Input
|Tran_date|Tran_date|
|---------|---------|
|01242022|064033|
|01222022|051003|

Output
|Der_datetime|
|------------|
|01-24-2022 06:40:33|
|01-22-2022 05:10:03|

Answer (score 1):

You can use `derived column` transformation in the **data flow** to convert the string to date time.

1. Using [concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#concat) function, combine the 2 columns  Tran_date & Tran_time and then convert to datetime using toTimestamp().

> [toTimestamp()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#totimestamp) function returns the default format as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:SSS`. If you want the DateTime in a different format, you can provide the output format later in sink transformation under mappings.

[image]

2. Using `select` transformation, you can delete unwanted columns which are passed to output/sink. (this is optional alternatively, you can edit the mappings in sink transformation to delete unwanted columns)

[image]

**Select transformation preview:**

[image]

3. In `sink` transformation, under **mapping**, you can provide your required DateTime **output format** as shown below.

[image]

**Sink preview:**

[image]

Comment: HI there the above expression is great, but when i use it i see nulls as  output. so i tried writing in below way.
toTimestamp(concat(substring(TRAN_DATE,1,4),'-',substring(TRAN_DATE,5,2),'-',substring(TRAN_DATE,7,2),' ',
substring(TRAN_TIME,1,2),':',substring(TRAN_TIME,3,2),':',substring(TRAN_TIME,5,2))) 
But this returning me milliseconds as well in the output which is not needed for me can you help me in formating the value 

Output i got from my above expression:
2021-11-08 09:45:54.000

I need output only 2021-11-08 09:45:54

Comment: Hi, did you add your date format type under sink mappings in output format as shown in step 3 in my answer?

Comment: Yes Niharika i put the outputformat